# Rails not loading in rspec file gives error "NameError: uninitialized constant" when accessing a model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, watir-webdriver

Rails rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 2.0.0

I am using watir-webdriver with rspec to test my web app. I want to pick the last item in a list where presence of an associated model is true. Basically the model on the page is Category, and in the list of categories I want to select the last one that has Tools associated with it. A Category has many Tools. My spec file:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.window.maximize

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) { @browser = browser }
  config.after(:suite) { browser.close unless browser.nil? }
end

url = 'localhost:3000'
serial = Time.now

describe 'it should log in and CRUD menu items' do

  it 'should log in' do
    @browser.goto url
    @browser.text_field(id: 'username').set Logins::user
    @browser.text_field(id: 'password').set Logins::password(url)
    @browser.button(:text, 'Login').click
    @browser.link(:text, 'Menu Settings').click
  end

  it 'should not delete a category with tools still associated with it' do
    category_name = Category.joins(:tools).where(true).order(name: :asc).last
    @browser.link(:text, category_name).click
    @browser.h4(class: 'tool_list')
    @browser.link(text: 'Delete').click
    @browser.driver.switch_to.alert.accept
    @browser.p(text: 'You can not destroy this menu item until it is empty').present?
  end
end
```

The line that is giving me the error is:

```
category_name = Category.joins(:tools).where(true).order(name: :asc).last
```

Not sure why I can't do a simple query in my spec file. I think I'm missing something really obvious.

**edit**
I updated my rspec version from 2 to 3 and ran:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

because I was missing the spec/rails_helper.rb file. Still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in Watir, but perhaps you have to require the file how defined your model ...

I think, perhaps, you have to require needed gems; like Active Record,
it's configuration, and initialisations files.

Comment: I'm thinking along those lines too. I don't have any "regular" Rspec tests in there. I'm assuming they will fail. But shouldn't it be loading the entire rails app so I can test it? Does that happen in spec_helper.rb?